# How do I test a button for focus and hover (screenshot/&::after)?

Tags: sass, hover, cypress

It seems that I cannot find a correct way of doing this in Cypress.

I want to test my buttons for hover and focus state.

First thing I tried was to take a screenshot of the whole component not just the buttons with cypress-image-snapshot when I use `realhover` on a element, but that doesn't seems to work.

Second thing I tried was via css but that also doesn't work because, when the element is in focus the background color of my `&::after` is changed via a `scss` variable, which I cannot get via cypress.

Has anyone any idea or has a solution for testing these states ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't go down the route of screenshots, rather test the element css when hovering.

But `.realHover()` from cypress-real-events is the easiest way to set up the test condition.

```js
cy.get('a[href="https://www.w3schools.com"]')
  .realHover()
  .then($el => {
    return window.getComputedStyle($el[0], ':after')  // pass pseudo in a 2nd parameter
      .getPropertyValue('background-color')
  })
  .should('eq', 'rgb(255, 255, 0)')  // ✅ passes
```

Tested with this page

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      :hover {
        --backgroundColor: yellow;
      }

      a::after {
        background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Demo of the :hover selector</h1>
    <p>The :hover selector style links on mouse-over:</p>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
    <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment out the `.realHover()` and the result is `rgb(0, 0, 0)`.

---

#### SCSS

Forget about the SCSS variable, it is compiled away when the page is served.

Cypress tests only see the resulting CSS.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the information, but sadly this doesn't work because my a tag background color is transparent while the &::after is blue, it compares transparent and not the &::after bg color

Comment: What is your SCSS code?

Comment: .btn::after {  content: '';   width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
    bottom: -0.7rem;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none; } and the var    :hover {--backgroundColor: #b0b8c0;}

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle()`  can get the styles for pseudos like `:after` by specifying it in a second parameter.

Comment: I plugged in your SCSS (compiled), added the `:after` param and the test still passes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already tried CSS variables and screenshots, you also give the following a try:

- **Triggering Events**: You can use `.trigger()` to manually trigger events like 'mouseover', 'mouseenter', 'focus', etc. After triggering these events, you can then assert the styles or behavior that should be present during hover or focus.
- **Stubbing or Spying**: If hover or focus triggers some function, you can use `cy.spy()` or `cy.stub()` to check if those functions are called.

Cypress operates directly on elements, so some browser behaviors like hover might not be exactly as in a real user interaction.

Comment: thanks, and how would I be able to get the background-color the &::after when using the trigger ? now I can only the bg of the a tag